# .htaccess redirect of a url to a url friendly subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain and I'm desperately trying to redirect a specific URL on it to another URL I have as a subdomain.
the subdomain use a friendly URL scheme.

I used the following in my .htaccess file but it didn't work for the query-string part.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.appninjaz.com
RewriteRule ^server/data/(.*)$ http://universe.appninjaz.com/data/$1 [L,R=301]
```

so basically, what I'm trying to do is:
redirect this URL: http://www.appninjaz.com/server/data/index.php?app_id=1
to this subdomain URL: http://universe.appninjaz.com/data/1

- app_id can be any number/id

Thank you,
Yaniv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.appninjaz.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} app_id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^server/data/index\.php$ http://universe.appninjaz.com/data/%1? [L,R=301]
```